Proving that a set is total in $l^{2}$
I have the following problem:

I have already done part a) of this question. I have tried to prove part b) by doing an $\epsilon$ argument but I couldn't. The definition of Schauder basis that I am using in my class is a set which is countable and total, i.e, the span is dense in $l^2$.
Any hint or help for this problem will be appreciated.

Show that any sequence orthogonal to each $x_m$ is $0.$

Please don’t use
images instead of typing your formulas

Let $\{\delta_m\}$ denote the standard orthonormal basis of $\ell^2.$ Then $$ \delta_m=x_m-{1\over 2}x_{m+1}$$ Therefore any element orthogonal to $x_m$ for every $m,$ is orthogonal to all $\delta_m,$ hence is equal $0.$ This shows that the family $\{x_m\}$ is total.
Moreover for any $a\in \ell^2$ we have $$a=\sum a_m\delta_m=\sum a_m\left (x_m-{1\over 2}x_{m+1}\right )= \sum a_mx_m-\sum {1\over 2}a_{m-1}x_m\\ =\sum \left ( a_m-{1\over 2}a_{m-1}\right )x_m $$ The representation holds entrywise, as the corresponding sums are finite. Moreover the series is convergent in $\ell^2$ as $$\sum_{m=1}^M\left ( a_m-{1\over 2}a_{m-1}\right )x_m\\ =\sum_{m=1}^Ma_mx_m-{1\over 2}\sum_{m=1}^{M-1}a_mx_{m+1}\\ =\sum_{m=1}^{M-1}a_m\delta_m+a_Mx_M\to a$$ Therefore $\{x_m\}$ forms a Schauder basis, according to the standard definition.
